# Delete using WHERE clause from the rows of the same table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, sql-delete

I'm having rows in the table which I intend to delete in MySQL:

```
delete from image_shout 
where auto_id in 
(
  select s.auto_id 
  from image_shout s 
  left join images i on s.image_id = i.image_id
  where i.image_id is null
);
```

For doing this I get an error:

> Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'image_shout' 
>       for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Mysql you can't select from a table you are deleting from. But you can trick it with another subquery.

```
delete from image_shout 
where auto_id in 
(
   select * from 
   (
     select s.auto_id 
     from image_shout s 
     left join images i on s.image_id = i.image_id 
     where i.image_id is null
   ) tmp_tbl
)
```

Or use a join directly in the delete statement

```
delete s 
from image_shout s
left join images i on s.image_id = i.image_id 
where i.image_id is null
```

Comment: I like the second alternative.